# gwt CheckBoxCell within CellList

Tags: java, gwt

Im trying to create a scrollPanel that holds a list of checkbox item. My main problem is constructing a CellList with CheckboxCell. Here is a snippet of whats causing the compile time error.

```
CheckboxCell testCheckBox = new CheckboxCell();

CellList<String> cellList = new CellList<String>(testCheckBox);
```

Error Message: The constructor CellList(CheckboxCell) is undefined.

If this is the wrong constructor, what is the correct way?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the type of CellList to Boolean.

```
CheckboxCell testCheckBox = new CheckboxCell();
CellList<Boolean> cellList = new CellList<Boolean>(testCheckBox);
```

**update:**

More examples on various cells (this is combined checkbox + picture, but you might want to replace picture with text):

http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTree

It's little trickier, but this showcase contains also sources so might want to dive into them.

PS: Lazier solution is not to use Cell Widgets and make own (extends Composite) combo/label and place it in say FlexTable :)

Comment: Thanks, that helps. However how would you associate text with the checkbox or vice versa.

Since you cannot use setRowData(), or else I am missing somthing.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like that. You are going to need some extra native code to handle the "check" event.

```
public class StyleCell extends AbstractCell<Style> {
@Override
public void render(Context context, Style row, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
    if (row == null) {
        return;
    }
    sb.appendHtmlConstant("<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME='property'>" + row.getProperty() + "</INPUT>");
}
```

}

```
StyleCell styleCell = new StyleCell();
CellList<Style> styleList = new CellList<Style>(styleCell);
```